# Certify the Web: DNS challange keeps changing

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm trying to make a * cert off my hosted services with the Community Edition of LetsEncrypt. I'm using the manual DNS update method.  Every time I try, it changes the DNS _acme-challenge value on me.  I'll go into my DNS manager, update my TXT, follow the instructions (Once completed, select 'Request Certificate' to resume.) It fails again, another message with a DIFFERENT txt.

Basically, every time I try, the TXT requirement changes...but I don't know where to find what it WILL want until it already changes it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it...TEST first, use that key, then REQUEST.

Comment: Keep in mind that LE certs are only good for 90 days. And you'll need to go through the TXT record challenge process each time you renew. So it's well worth your time to switch from the manual method to a DNS plugin that works with your provider so the renewal process can be automated.